# Chop 4 sides of image with Imagemagick

Tags: bash, shell, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following image:

```
test PNG 1366x655 1366x655+0+0 8-bit sRGB 286KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

and I need to chop it like this from the border of the image:

```
top: 140 px
bottom: 140 px
left: 180 px
right: 60 px
```

Is there a one-line command line to do this with `convert`?

Comment: Congrats on SO bash question number 100,000!

Comment: Wow! thanks dude =D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can combine two `-crop`s:

```
                      #left,top      right,bottom
convert test.png -crop +180+140 -crop -60-140 cropped.png
```

Comment: great solution, it works perfectly, thanks!, just to point out that it should be `convert test.png -crop +180+140 -crop -60-140 cropped.png` considering the left (+180 px), top (+140 px), right (-60 px) and bottom (-140 px) directions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The solution from `that other guy` is very clever. The standard way would be to use -chop. But that means 4 calls, since there is no symmetry in the sizes to be removed. So in ImageMagick using -chop, you could do

```
convert text.png -gravity north -chop 0x180 -gravity east -chop 60x0 -gravity south -chop 0x140 -gravity west -chop 140x0 cropped.png
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop

See also -shave when there is symmetry either left/right or top/bottom or all around. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave

Answer (score 2):

Another method using V7

> magick input -crop "%[fx:w-(180+60)]"x"%[fx:h-(140+140)]"+180+140
>   result

Answer (score 1):

Building upon Bonzo's solution, you can do something similar in ImageMagick 6 using viewport cropping (Unix syntax):

```
top=140
bottom=140
left=180
right=60
convert image.png -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:w-$left-$right]x%[fx:h-$top-$bottom]+${left}+${top}" -filter point +distort SRT 0 +repage result.png
```